# call a function when submit form

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, input, submit

I'm trying to call a function when submit form , this function showld work for all forms with div "#js_ajax_form".
( the javascript code works in chrome console
// html code

```
     <form method="post" id="js_ajax_form" data-type="user.registration" action="signup">


                        <input type="text" name="val[first_name]" id="first_name" placeholder="First Name" value="" size="30">


                        <input type="text" name="val[last_name]" id="last_name" placeholder="Last Name" value="" size="30">




                    <input type="submit" value="Sign Up" class="button_register" id="js_registration_submit">

        </form>

// javascript

    var $Core = {};
    function getParam(sParam)
    {
    return oParams[sParam];
    }


    $Core.form = function()
    {
    $("#js_ajax_form").submit(function(e)
    {
        var postData = $(this).serializeArray();

        alert(postData);

        e.preventDefault(); //STOP default action
        e.unbind(); //unbind. to stop multiple form submit.
    }); 


    }
```

Comment: `all forms with div "#js_ajax_form"` <- there can be only one ?

Comment: If the **`div`** has the `id` `js_ajax_form`, then the problem is that `div` elements don't have a `submit` event. It's very hard to tell what your question is, without seeing the HTML.

Comment: @user3053207: adeneo's point is that you cannot use the same `id` on more than one element in the document. The whole point of an `id` is that it's *unique*.

Comment: i've updated  with html code

Comment: @costapombo i don't see any div in that code...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

as long as you are using jQuery, the following code should work:

```
$("#myform").submit(function() {
   myFunction();
   // the form will continue on submission
});
```